# Online Server is Running Partial App

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have uploaded my codeigniter app on a live server. It is not working fine. After successful login, I can view certain pages while some main pages (Controllers) throw following error:

> The www.abc.com page isn’t working.
>
> www.abc.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: check web server logs. 500 is internal server error

Comment: You might show the offending controllers